# Turning a set of random walk data 45 degrees

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, data, random

I have a set of data that is just a "random" (generated by me, not by computer) sequence of length 2000 of 1's and (-1)'s. I used it to plot a 1-D random walk where +1 is step up, (-1) is step down, so my graph looked like this:
[image]

I was asked to break the sequence in half and plot the first half against the second to create a 2-D random walk graph. This was easy enough, I just did it in excel.
[image]

But I was then asked to turn the graph 45 degrees CCW so it looks like it's laid over a grid.
So i guess if the first point is (1,1) it would go to (0,1), if it's (-1,1) it would go to (-1,0) and so on. I'm not sure how to do that. Please let me know if you know of a way to do it in Excel or *Mathematica*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ListLinePlot[Accumulate @ Prepend[RandomChoice[{{-1, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, -1}, {0, 1}}, 1000], 
  {1, 1}], AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

> [image]

Starting with some random data

```
rd = RandomChoice[{1, -1}, 2000];

ListLinePlot[Accumulate@rd]
```

> [image]

Creating a random walk similar to the one shown in your question

```
rw = Accumulate@Transpose[{rd[[;; 1000]], rd[[1001 ;;]]}];

ListLinePlot[rw, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

> [image]

and rotating it by 45°

```
rwr = rw.(RotationMatrix[45 Degree]/Sqrt[2]);

ListLinePlot[rwr, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

> [image]

Comment: Oo! Very nice :] But I need to do that with the data that I already have. The whole point is that it's not randomly generated by a computer, but randomly generated by a person.

Comment: @Solarmew In my edit I show a way how to start with random data similar to yours, create the 2D random walk the same way you did, and than rotate it by 45 degrees.

Comment: @Solarmew Do you want the rotated data to be on a 1 x 1 grid as shown in the last plot of my answer or on a Sqrt[2] x Sqrt[2] grid as shown in the other answers?

Comment: Yours came out awesome :] Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for. I'm not really sure what the differences are. The other answers work great too. I don't know Mathematica well enough to know which one is the most optimized, but they all do the job :D

Comment: Rotation is clockwise instead of CCW.  see my solution in this thread for correct answer

Comment: @penguin77 Rotation is 45 degrees. For a -45 degrees rotation just replace `RotationMatrix[45 Degree]` with `RotationMatrix[-45 Degree]`.

Answer (score 4):

```
rw = Accumulate@RandomChoice[{-1, 1}, 400];
ListLinePlot[rw, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

```
rw2 = Transpose[{rw[[ ;; 200]], rw[[201 ;; ]]}];

llp2 = ListLinePlot[rw2, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

To rotate `llp2`:

```
Show[MapAt[GeometricTransformation[#, RotationTransform[-45 Degree]] &,
   llp2, {1}], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Aside: Using `InterpolationOrder->0` gives "axes-aligned" lines (but it does not actually correspond to `rw2`)

```
ListLinePlot[rw2, AspectRatio -> 1, InterpolationOrder -> 0]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

No need folding 1D graph to get a 2D Random walk in Mathematica. and the CCW easy in Mathematica. Here we go:

Generate data set for the random sequence with 2000 steps. Alternatively, you may use your "own generated" data set.

```
rdata = Accumulate[RandomChoice[{-1, 1}, {2000, 2}]]
```

Now plot it with similar layout as your example

```
ListLinePlot[rdata, GridLines -> {{0}, Range[-40, 30, 10]}]
```

Here the result (Nicer than Excel...much nicer,hi,hi,hi)
[image]

Now you wish to turn it CCW, for whatever reason? Ok no problem
Create a Transformation Function

```
r = RotationTransform[45 Degree, {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}]
```

Apply this function....

```
 ListLinePlot[r @ rdata , GridLines -> {{0}, Range[-40, 30, 10]}]
```

[image]

What you mean with Excel??? never heard about it...hi,hi,hi