# Generating a random walk that can move right, left, up and down

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, random

Suppose that we have a dice with 4 faces. If the dice lands on:

1. the person will move to the right
2. the person will move to the left
3. the person will move upward
4. the person will move downward

The simulation has `n` steps and the position of the person updates on every step. How can I generate this random simulation?

```
test[n_] := Accumulate[RandomChoice[{{-1, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, -1}}, n]]
```

How can I show the first/last point on the simulation if I use a function similar to `ListLinePlot[test[10]]`?

Comment: Look at RandomChoice

Comment: See http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/57561/18476

Comment: Also http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/78351

Comment: test[n_] := 
 Accumulate[RandomChoice[{{-1, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, -1}}, n]],

How can i plot this,

Comment: `ListLinePlot[#, PlotRange -> All, Mesh -> All, 
   Epilog -> {Red, Point@Last@#}, AspectRatio -> Automatic] &@test[10]`

Answer (score 3):

You might implement your random walk something like this.

```
walk[n_] := 
  Prepend[
    Accumulate[RandomChoice[{{-1, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, -1}}, n]], 
    {0, 0}]

trial[n_] := 
  Module[{path, start, end},
    path = walk[n];
    start = First @ path;
    end = Last @ path;
    ListLinePlot[path,
      Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Point[start], Red, Point[end]},
      AspectRatio -> Automatic]]

SeedRandom[3]; trial[25]
```

[image: walk]

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

SeedRandom[123];
walk[n_Integer, init_ : {0, 0}] := Module[{
   up = {0, 1},
   dn = {0, -1},
   right = {1, 0},
   left = {-1, 0}
   },
  steps = RandomChoice[{left, right, up, dn}, n];
  FoldList[Plus, init, steps]
  ]

walk[10, {1, 1}]  (*starting at {1,1} with 10 steps *)
```

> {{1, 1}, {2, 1}, {2, 0}, {3, 0}, {2, 0}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}, {2,
> 4}, {1, 4}, {0, 4}}

---

*Visualization:*

```
With[{n = 30},
 path = walk[n, {2, 2}] // Echo;
 ListLinePlot[Partition[path, 2, 1], AspectRatio -> Automatic
   , PlotStyle -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][#] & /@ Subdivide[n - 1])
   , PlotLegends -> Placed[BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {0, n}}], After]
   , PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.15]
   , AspectRatio -> Automatic
   , Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize@Large, Black
     , Point@path[[1]], Circle[path[[1]], 0.2]
     , Red, Point@path[[-1]], Circle[path[[-1]], 0.2]
     }
   ] /. Line[a__] :> Arrow[a, 0.05]
 ]
```

---

[image]

Comment: +1, but I get lots of error messages, which only go away after deleting `/. Line[a__] :> Arrow[a, 0.05]`

Comment: I am on v12.2 and copied code on this page to a fresh notebook.  I get no error messages. Can you please include message information. Thanks for including information about the Arrow.

Comment: I'm on Version 13.3.0 and must delete the last line (the line to arrow transformation). Fresh kernel doesn't help.

Comment: You can start it as a new question by adding a minimal example. Perhaps it is a recently introduced bug. In the meantime, I will request the readers to provide more feedback and mention their version info as well. Thanks.