# Programming a 2D random walk

Tags: random

I have these functions

```
Randomwalk1[n_] :=Accumulate[2*RandomInteger[{0, 1}, n] - 1];

Randomwalk2[n_] := NestList[# + 2*RandomInteger[{0, 1}] - 1 &, 0, n]
```

that are random walks in 1D and I have to modify them to get a random walk in 2D, the walker can move right, left, step back or move forward with same probability 1/4 .. I'm a beginner and really don't know how to do that..

Thanks

I was thinking about an other way to do that without using these functions but I don't know if it can work and don't know how to do that in mathematica, here is the idea

if `RandomInteger[{1,2}]=1` the walker moves in x direction

and if `RandomInteger[{1,2}]=2` the walker moves in y direction

Then we call `2*RandomInteger[{0, 1}] - 1` to randomly generate -1 or +1 and the walker makes this step in the direction that was first determined

Comment: Have you seen `RandomChoice[]`?

Comment: We didn't see a lot ! But we have the right to use everything in mathematica

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: From the help `data2d = RandomFunction[RandomWalkProcess[0.5], {0, 10^3}, 2];
Graphics[Line[Transpose@data2d["States"]], AspectRatio -> Automatic]`

Comment: A shorter version for your one-dimensional problem using `RandomChoice` as suggested by @J.M.: `randomwalk[n_] := Accumulate[RandomChoice[{-1, 1}, n]]`. The extension to the 2D case that you are asking for would read: `randomwalk2d[n_] := Accumulate[RandomChoice[{-1, 1}, {n, 2}]]`.

Comment: Thanks ! I have to find the average position for a walk but the thing is I don't get what it means. Do I have to extract the position after every step, put that in a table, and sum them than divide them by the number of steps ? Whats would be the easiest way to do that in mathematica ?

Comment: I suppose the "average position for a walk" can be obtained by running several random walks and taking the `Mean` on the last position of the outputs. You may want to use `N` at some point in case you want numerical values.

Comment: @Xavier "average position for a walk" could also be a poor way of describing the mean squared displacement...

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/78351/18476

Comment: @blochwave Yes I agree, this would be an unfortunate wording though.

Comment: worth pointing out, if you only care about the final position, in this case order doesn't matter and you can just do this `Total /@ Transpose[ RandomChoice[{{1, 0}, {-1, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, -1}}, n] `  (I expect substantially faster for large n )

Answer (score 8):

I am also new. But I think the following works

```
randomwalk[n_] := 
 NestList[move := 
   RandomChoice[{{1, 0}, {-1, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, -1}}]; # + move &, {0, 
   0}, n]
```

Comment: You can make your code a little simpler with: `Randomwalk[n_] := 
 NestList[# + RandomChoice[{{1, 0}, {-1, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, -1}}] &, {0, 
   0}, n]`.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
    Manipulate[
 list = Accumulate[RandomInteger[{-1, 1}, {stepsNumber, 3}]];
 xmin = Min[(Transpose@list)[[1]]];
 xmax = Max[(Transpose@list)[[1]]];
 ymin = Min[(Transpose@list)[[2]]];
 ymax = Max[(Transpose@list)[[2]]];
 zmin = Min[(Transpose@list)[[3]]];
 zmax = Max[(Transpose@list)[[3]]];

 Animate[

  Show[{
    Graphics3D[{Blue, Line[Take[list, i]]}],
    Graphics3D[{Darker@Red, Arrowheads[0.03], Thickness[0.005], 
      Arrow[{First[list], list[[i]]}]}]
    }, PlotRange -> {{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}, {zmin, zmax}}, 
   ImageSize -> {400, 400}],
  {i, 2, Length[list], 1}, AnimationRepetitions -> 1, 
  AnimationRunning -> False], {{stepsNumber, 2


   }, ControlType -> InputField, FieldSize -> 7}, 
 SaveDefinitions -> False]
```

Put an integer number (say, 10000) into the input field and press the arrow button. 
That's what you should get:

[image]

Have fun!